# What are scientists actually improving?

Tags: startopia

In Startopia, when you have a laboratory, you can research new technologies, new rooms, new equipment.

However, when you don't give anything to work on to your scientists, they will randomly spend their time "improving an existing technology".

What is the actual effect of this improvement?

Comment: "Now it has lasers!" But how does that impr- "shhh. Lasers."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you research an item, while already having all of the new technologies it provides, you will reduce the factory cost of that item.

If you research without an item, an item you already have researched is chosen, and the factory cost of that item will be reduced.

Comment: Apparently, it also [decreases the time](http://startopia.wikia.com/wiki/Laboratory) it takes to produce the item in a factory. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yeah, it does... but usually the factory is so well-manned that construction time isn't an issue.

Comment: I've also read that improving litter increases the energy gain from recyclers, but I'm not sure if it's verified.

Comment: Don't forget that researching plants from the biodeck will also make those plants grow faster.